# How do I add username and password agent to a VM created from disk in azure

Tags: python, azure, virtual-machine

I have **created a VM from a disk in azure** using the following command on **CLI**-

> az vm create --resource-group RESOURCE-GRP-NAME --location eastus --name
>   VM-NAME --os-type linux --attach-os-disk DISK-NAME

The VM gets created successfully, but as there is no option to specify user name and password, I am not able to connect to this VM from my terminal via ssh.

Also, in the properties of the created VM, it shows **AGENT STATUS** as **NOT READY**. Is this also an problem?

I want to connect to the created VM successfully, please suggest something.

Comment: Are you getting any error message while SSH into the VM?
Refer the below linux VM SSH troubleshooting guidence:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/troubleshoot-ssh-connection

Comment: When I go to reset password, it says that VM Agent is unavailable. How to install this VM agent via CLI? Or ho do I provide my credentials like username and password through a command from CLI? please sugget. @VikranthS

Comment: Does this disk upload from local?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT I have copied data from other os disk to a new disk. And from this created a new VM.

Comment: @PiyushDoke Could you show me how do you copy that OS disk?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT using Rsync command

Comment: @PiyushDoke Powershell or CLI?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT on CLI.

Comment: @PiyushDoke could you ssh to that VM?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT The VM gets created successfully and in the Azure portal, it shoes the status as running, but I am not able to SSH to the VM from my terminal. And when I add the parameters [--admin-passord] & [--admin-username], it gives error as NOT APPLICATBLE to --attach-os-disk

Comment: @PiyushDoke Not able to SSH it, do you mean your password is wrong?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT it is not asking me for passord. And I am not able to give the username in the first place......In the command above, I cannot add username and passord but I can create a VM. How do I add password and username

Comment: @PiyushDoke Azure does not support add username and password for OS disk, have you stop that original VM then copy that OS disk?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT with the command: [az vm create......--attach-os-disk], a NEW VM is created. How to resolve the issue of username and password if azure does not support adding username and password.

Comment: @PiyushDoke use managed disk or unmanaged disk?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT I used managed disk

Comment: @PiyushDoke If you want to use that OS to deploy new VM and add new username and password, you should create image.

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT okay, means from that disk, first I should create Image and then from this image I should deploy new VM?

Comment: @PiyushDoke Yes, if you deploy VM from image, you will able to specify username and password:) I have update my answer, please check it, after capture image from that VM, the original will not able to login, so you should backup that OS disk first.

Comment: @PiyushDoke But you copy OS disk and use that disk to create new VM should be able to login, why that does not work for you? could you please copy that OS disk and create it again? Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-linux-cli-sample-copy-managed-disks-to-same-or-different-subscription) to copy os disk.

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT I have OS data of an AWS vm (ubuntu instance) stored into a disk in azure, and I am creating VM from this disk. So there are no credentials like user name and password in the disk as AWS does not require it. Sorry I completely forgot to mention about the aws part in the above discussion.

Comment: @PiyushDoke have you install waagent before upload to azure?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT No, I directly created the VM using the command mentioned in the question. Where do I need to upload this waagent (VM agent)? while creating VM or before creating VM? or on the disk?

Comment: @PiyushDoke You should follow this article to prepare VHD, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-upload-ubuntu?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2flinux%2ftoc.json

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT As you suggested, I tried to create a VHD in AWS, but you can only export an ec2 instance if it was originally imported into AWS. Any instance you create on ec2 cannot be imported using Amazon's tools. So I am unable to create the VHD in the first place only. Can you please suggest me any other ay of migrating my ec2 instance to azure vm

Comment: @PiyushDoke Sorry for my mistake, Azure'S vhd is not same as AWS's VDH, AWS Ubuntu is not support to migrate to Azure, please check my answer, Sorry again:(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my mistake.

For now, there is no direct way to achieve this.

We can migrate Amazon Web Services VMs to Azure via **Microsoft Azure site recovery**.  But that just work for:

> These EC2 instance should be running the 64-bit version of Windows
>   Server 2008 R2 SP1 or later, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012
>   R2, Windows Server 2016, or Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.7 (HVM
>   virtualized instances only). The server must have only Citrix PV or
>   AWS PV drivers. Instances running RedHat PV drivers aren't supported.

**Ubuntu is not supported.**

More information about Migrate AWS instances to Azure, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/tutorial-migrate-aws-to-azure).